# PhpStorm dynamic type hinting class property

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using a builder pattern to create an object, call methods, and return back to the calling object.

```
class Caller{

    public function invoke() {
        new Builder($this)->setColor('red')->setSize(5)-> // need typehint for Caller to return here
    }

    public function next() {

    }

}

class Builder{

    /**
     * @var ????
     */
    private $caller;

    /**
     * @param ???? $caller
     */
    public function __construct($caller) {
        $this->caller = $caller;
    }

    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $size
     * @return ????
     */
    public function setSize($size) {
        $this->size = $size;
        return $this->caller;
    }
}
```

There is a way to invoke a `parent` method and return the `child` typehints by specifying `$this` as the return type in the parent class, but how can I reference a separate class type stored in `$this->caller` as the return type and get the typehints?

Comment: Guess you're looking for [generics](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics). Hopefully someday! In the meantime, unless I'm missing something, you'll have to split your statement into two (with `/** @var Caller $yourCallerName */` on top of the first one) if you want autocompletion.

Comment: i realized in my case i can actually get away with using my class name as there's only 1 class so far that i'll be calling from